Is there a way to reference a bslib theme in R Markdown without using the YAML parameters?
I'd like to use the bslib package to create a custom theme for my R Markdown file. However, in all the resources I can find, it looks like the theme has to be created in the YAML header using the theme parameter and its arguments. Instead, I'd like to reference a bslib theme, similarly to how CSS files are referenced. For example,
output: 
  html_document:
    css: "style.css"

But instead, something like:
output:
  html_document:
    theme: my_theme

Thanks!

This page describes some clear ways to use bslib with a theme. Here I use one of the examples as mentioned in the link:
---
output:
  html_document:
    theme:
      bg: "#101010"
      fg: "#FFF"
      primary: "#E69F00"
      secondary: "#0072B2"
      success: "#009E73"
      base_font:
        google: "Prompt"
      code_font:
        google: "JetBrains Mono"
---

# R Markdown example

Some example text to demonstrate!

Output:


Right, I don't want to define the theme in the YAML of the R Markdown, I'd like to reference a theme created in a different file.
